# Delete all unused categories in Wordpress via SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a project with thousands of categories where most of them are no longer being used. I have tried a couple SQL commands to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need to look at the `wp_term_taxonomy` table to get the categories with a count of 0 (and maybe a specific taxonomy), then remove those from the `wp_terms` table.

Comment: First, I'm a SQL noob. I've only had of couple hours on how to SELECT, etc. I am working with this: DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'category' AND term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships) and this: DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id NOT IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy) But, I guess I need some examples to help me understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should get you where you need.

```
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE count = 0)
```

You defintely want to delete the terms from the `wp_terms` table, not `wp_term_taxonomy`

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.